# Can I use CAST with a SELECT SUM command in Sqlite3?

Tags: python, sqlite

I can't find a way to convert the SUM of multiple rows into an integer instead of a str. I tried use CAST but when I print(type) print(variable) it shows that it is a list instead of an INT. This is the code I used

```
("SELECT CAST(SUM(prices) AS INT) FROM transactions WHERE id =" + id.get())
```

Shouldn't the output be an INT instead of list/str?

Comment: If you use `your_cursor.fetch_one(...)` to execute your select in Python, it should return only a value instead of a list ot row results.

Comment: @progmatico it returns the a value but it is inside a parenthesis with a comma in the end.

Comment: That's a tuple of rows not a list. Like with a list,  add [0] in front gives you the value, but I suppose that is what you are trying to avoid...

Comment: I added [0] and it works for me. Thank you.